# php design pattern for nealy similar json response

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'd like to write a small class in php which gets latitude and longitude values from different GEO-APIs (like Google Maps or osm nominatim). Both providers return similar results as json but with different keys.

In getCordinates() you see the parsing for Google's api. Is there a nice design pattern that I do not have to spoil the method with several if statements for every new geo provider and blow up the method but keep things separated?

```
public $googleEndPoint = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
public $OSMendPoint =  "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=";
public $endpoint;
public $address;


function __construct($endpoint = 'google'){
    switch ($endpoint){
        case 'OSM':
            $this->endpoint = $this->OSMendPoint;
            break;
        default:
            $this->endpoint = $this->googleEndPoint;
        break; 
    }
}


function request(){
    $address = urlencode($this->address);
    $result = file_get_contents($this->endpoint.$address); 
    $response = json_decode($result, true);
    return $response;
}


function getCoordinates($address) {
    $this->address = $address;
    $response = $this->request();
    // this is google specific and does not fit for other provider
    if( $response['status']=='OK' ){
        $data_arr['lat'] = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; 
        $data_arr['lon'] = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];  
        $data_arr['formatted_address'] = $response['results'][0]['formatted_address'];   
            return $data_arr;            
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: probably not. no one says that API 'x' has to return data back in the same format as API 'y', especially if there's no governing standards for it.

Comment: I would probably just create a wrapper interface with standard methods for your use case then implement it for each GEO provider.

Comment: I agree with @bassxzero. One Provider per web service, which all implement a common GeoProvider interface. And if there is common logic like in your `request` method you may have (some off) them extend a common abstract parent.

Comment: Hi Pevara with Provider you mean classes? Means I would have class googleGeocoder and OSMGeocoder which both implements f.e. GeocoderInterface. This interface would define all needed methods which the classes give a sligthly different body?

Comment: and one more point, I´ve read about adapter pattern. Would this fit here as well? – to write an adapter for the different json API returns?

Comment: Adapter connects different interfaces (implements one, depends on the other). You need different algorithms - polymorphism is the way to go.